# How do I add values of a row based on two unique identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns that I am interested in they are Id, Week and Time.
My select will look like this.

```
SELECT Id, Week, Time FROM TimeSheet
```

This is the result

```
+------+------+------+
| Id   | Week | Time |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | 8.0  |
|    1 |    1 | 8.0  |
|    2 |    3 | 8.0  |
|    2 |    4 | 8.0  |
|    3 |    5 | 8.0  |
|    3 |    5 | 3.0  |
|    3 |    5 | 8.0  |
|    3 |    5 | 8.0  |
+------+------+------+
```

The result that I would like is to have it sorted by id and week where time is added together per week so that I can see how much each Id worked per week.
I really have no idea of how to achieve this, it'm not a developer.

```
+------+------+------+
| Id   | Week | Time |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | 16.0 |
|    2 |    3 |  8.0 |
|    2 |    4 |  8.0 |
|    3 |    5 | 27.0 |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: What data type is "Time"?  it seems odd to have a comma separation and that it's left aligned (usually varchar)

Comment: If it is numeric and it actually works, do not use the `CONVERT` as it will be an overhead :)

Comment: Numeric datatype will not accept commas right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real problem i see with your data is that time seems to be a string an not a number, so in order to SUM it you would need to convert it to a numeric data type before SUMing it.

```
SELECT Id, 
       Week, 
       SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,REPLACE(Time,',','.'))) 
FROM   TimeSheet 
GROUP BY Id, Week
```

Saying that, i would suggest keeping your data in the correct data type. If the `Time` column is supposed to keep a numeric value, please make it of a numeric data type.

Choosing the correct Data Type will help you keep your DB cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id, Week, SUM(Time)
FROM TimeSheet
GROUP BY Id, Week
```